# Limit of two variables function

Tags: limits

I think that 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \left(\frac{3}{2y}-\frac yx\right)^2+\left(\frac 1y-\frac yx\right)^2=+\infty$$

But I can’t find a way to prove it. 
I first tried expanding the squares to find a reduction, but it gave me nothing.
I tried polar coordinates, but I’m also stuck this way.
I tried to write some minorization using $\dfrac 1{(xy)^2}\geqslant\dfrac 4{(x^2+y^2)^2}$.
Any idea?

Comment: Use $y=mx$ and prove the limit doesn't depend on $m$

Comment: @N74 That won't work, since not all paths to the origin are of the form $y=mx$.

Comment: I tried polar coordinates, many unsuccessful minorizations, I even tried to prove I’m wrong using special cases, but I’m convinced the limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: @Azozo You're right. See my answer.

Comment: @Frpzzd, N74 is saying that a necessary condition for the limit to exist is for all linear trajectories (y=mx), the limit does not depend on m. He wishes to show the contrapositive.  I haven’t verified but if it does not depend on m, you are right we need to consider other paths as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, the limit cannot be negative, since it is the sum of the squares of two functions of $x$ and $y$. Try the following.

Suppose that
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \bigg(\frac{3}{2y}-\frac{y}{x}\bigg)^2$$
does not diverge to $\infty$. Then the limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \bigg(\frac{3}{2y}-\frac{y}{x}\bigg)\tag{1}$$
does not diverge to $\pm\infty$. However, since $1/2y$ must diverge to $\pm\infty$ as $y\to 0$, and since
$$\frac{3}{2y}-\frac{y}{x}-\frac{1}{2y}=\frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{x}$$
it follows that if the limit $(1)$ doesn't diverge to $\pm\infty$, then the following limit *will*:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \bigg(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{x}\bigg)\tag{2}$$
Thus, either the limit $(1)$ or the limit $(2)$ or both diverge to positive or negative infinite values, meaning that the sum of their squares
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \bigg(\frac{3}{2y}-\frac{y}{x}\bigg)^2+\bigg(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{x}\bigg)^2$$
diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: I don’t understand your reasoning, because it looks like neither of these two limits exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the first expression as:

$\Big( \frac{3}{2y}-\frac{y}{x} \Big)^2=\Big( \frac{1}{2y}+\frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{x} \Big)^2$

Hence:

$\Big( \frac{1}{2y}+\frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{x} \Big)^2=\frac{1}{4y^2}+\frac{2}{2y}\Big(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{x} \Big)+\Big( \frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{x} \Big)^2-\Big( \frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{x} \Big)^2=$

$=\frac{1}{4y^2}+\Big( \frac{1}{y^2}-\frac{1}{x} \Big)=\frac{1}{4y^2}+\frac{x-y^2}{xy^2}=\frac{x+4x-4y^2}{4xy^2}$

This is an expression easier to work with $r\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I think there’s a mistake where you both add an subtract the same square.

Comment: I was using the formula $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$. for $a=\frac{1}{2y}$ and $b=\frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it using @Frpzzd’s idea.
Let $$f(x,y)=\left(\frac 3{2y}-\frac yx\right)^2+\left(\frac 1y-\frac yx\right)^2$$
for all $(x,y)$ such that $xy\neq 0$.
For such $(x,y)$, we have $f(x,y)=f(x,-y)$ so we may assume that $y<0$.
If we don’t have $\displaystyle\lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\ y<0}} f(x,y)=+\infty$, there exists an $A>0$ and two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$, with $y_n<0$ for all $n$, such that $\lim x_n=\lim y_n=0$ and $f(x_n,y_n)<A^2$ for all $n$.
Hence, for all $n$,
$$\left(\frac 3{2y_n}-\frac{y_n}{x_n}\right)^2<A^2$$
and
$$\left(\frac 1{y_n}-\frac {y_n}{x_n}\right)^2<A^2$$
From these two inequalities, we get for all $n$:
$$-A<\frac 3{2y_n}-\frac{y_n}{x_n}<A$$
$$-A-\frac 1{2y_n}<\frac 1{y_n}-\frac {y_n}{x_n}<A$$
$$-\frac 1{2y_n}<\frac 1{y_n}-\frac {y_n}{x_n}+A<2A$$
But $$\lim -\frac 1{2y_n}=+\infty$$, hence this sequence can’t be bounded from above by $2A$.
It proves that $$\lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\ y<0}} f(x,y)=+\infty$$, hence the result.